# How to access bloc state properties that don't exist in the base state class?

Tags: flutter, oop, bloc, flutter-bloc

Consider these states:

```dart
class ExerciseInitialState extends ExerciseState {}

class ExerciseLoadingState extends ExerciseState {}

class ExerciseLoadedState extends ExerciseState {
  final List<Data> data;

  const ExerciseLoadedState({required this.data});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [data];

  // total count
  int get totalCount => data.length;
}
```

In the UI, I have to cast the state (`ExerciseState`) to `ExerciseLoadedState` to be able to access its property which doesn't exist in the `ExerciseLoadingState` and `ExerciseInitialState`:

```dart
final total = (context.read<ExerciseBloc>().state as ExerciseLoadedState).totalCount
```

It looks awkward to me to have to do this casting all the time. Is the only solution to add the same properties to the base class `ExerciseState`?

Comment: Can you include events and bloc?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I don't know why you need to see events and bloc pages but there's nothing in those files, they are just empty bloc and event classes.

Comment: I was thinking about testing the code.

Comment: add the getter inside the base class: int get totalCount = 0; and override it in the LoadedState

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not feel wrong to you - if you want the property to be available in all the state classes, it should be defined in the base class. E.g. you cannot get the `totalCount` while the state is `ExerciseLoadingState` simply because this property is not defined here - you need to promote the type to a specific one.

There are two possible solutions to this problem:

1. Promote the type to `ExerciseLoadedState` to access the property:

```
return BlocBuilder<ExerciseBloc, ExerciseState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    final totalCount = state is ExerciseLoadedState
        ? (state as ExerciseLoadedState).totalCount
        : 0;
  },
);
```

2. Create an extension method on `ExerciseState`:

```
extension ExerciseStateX on ExerciseState {
  int get totalCount => this is ExerciseLoadedState
      ? (this as ExerciseLoadedState).totalCount
      : 0;
}
```

With the extension, you won't need to do the type promotion in your UI layer.